# Subqueries in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, subquery, join

I've been trying for a couple of days to write to "translate" this query in LINQ with no success so far. Could you guys please help me? I would also appreciate some explanation to learn actually something out of it.

Here is the T-SQL query:

```
SELECT R.ResourceID, R.DefaultValue
FROM Resources as R
JOIN
    (SELECT [t0].[NameResourceID] AS [ResourceID]
    FROM [dbo].[Sectors] AS [t0]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[LocalizedResources] AS [t1] ON [t0].[NameResourceID] = [t1].[ResourceID] and [t1].[LanguageID] = 2
    WHERE t1.Value IS NULL)  AS subQ 

ON R.ResourceID = subQ.ResourceID
```

Thank's

Comment: Why are you "JOINING" to that subQ... you're not pulling a single value out of there. That should be a WHERE clause as all you are doing is using it to filter. That's probably why you're having a hard time translating it.

Comment: All I need is the IDs of those entries from subQ. Indeed, I use it only for filtering. I just couldn't find a better solution. Do you have any suggestions?

Basically I am trying to find all the resources that were not localized in the language X  and then see if there are any sectors among them.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
from r in db.Resources
join subQ in (from t0 in db.Sectors
              join t1 in db.LocalizedResources on t0.NameResourceID equals t1.ResourceID
              where t1.LanguageId
              && t1.Value == null
              select new { ResourceID = t0.NameResourceID }) on r.ResourceID equals subQ.ResourceID
select new { r.ResourceId, r.DefaultValue };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It gets translated in TSQL into: 

SELECT [t0].[ResourceID], [t0].[DefaultValue]
FROM [dbo].[Resources] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN 
 ([dbo].[Sectors] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[LocalizedResources] AS [t2] ON [t1].[NameResourceID] = [t2].[ResourceID]) ON [t0].[ResourceID] = [t1].[NameResourceID]
WHERE 0 = 1

I've tried to modify it but I couldn't get any better.